# Longer EU stay for retired couple

Tags: visas, schengen

We have early retirement. My husband has a EU (Dutch) passport and US (Dual citizen) I only have a US and would like to travel through Europe without the 90 day limitations. Is this possible? To clarify, we just want to travel greater than 3 months in EU countries, not live there....

Comment: UD? Do you mean US?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is, as long as you are traveling with (or to join) your husband.  You can be, strictly speaking, required to register if you stay in any country for longer than 90 days, but if you're planning to travel around you'll be fine.  The requirement to register is controlled by national law, so the specifics will vary depending on where you are.

All of this is governed by [Directive 2004/38/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616) concerning the right of freedom of movement.  To prove that you qualify under the directive, you may be asked to show a copy of your marriage certificate, so you should keep one with you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a residency permit in any of the Schengen countries and then you may travel freely.

http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm

I also recommend contacting them by phone, I have contacted them in the past and cleared doubts similar to the one you have.

Comment: She will unlikely be eligible to apply for a residence card if they are not establishing a base in an EU country for at least three months. In such a case, though, the non-EU spouse does not need a residence card. If they *are* planning to have a base in some EU country, though, the residence card could simplify certain things. It could also complicate other things, however, like making it necessary to get a driver's license from the country issuing the residence card.  Finally, the husband is Dutch, so establishing a base in the Netherlands would be more difficult than in another EU country.